# How get all camel component poperties using java code

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am tring to get camel component properties using java code like:

```
Configuration: 
Java: 11
Apache Camel: 3.18.2
```

for Example:
if pass **Kafka** component in java code, get all the latest properties from Apache camel:

get all properties of Kafka :

**additionalProperties, brokers, clientId, headerFilterStrategy, reconnectBackoffMaxMs, shutdownTimeout,    allowManualCommit, autoCommitEnable, autoCommitIntervalMs, autoOffsetReset, breakOnFirstError, checkCrcs,   commitTimeoutMs, consumerRequestTimeoutMs, consumersCount, fetchMaxBytes, fetchMinBytes, fetchWaitMaxMs, groupId,   groupInstanceId, headerDeserializer, heartbeatIntervalMs, keyDeserializer, maxPartitionFetchBytes,  maxPollIntervalMs, maxPollRecords, offsetRepository, partitionAssignor, pollOnError, pollTimeoutMs, seekTo,     sessionTimeoutMs, specificAvroReader, topicIsPattern, valueDeserializer, bridgeErrorHandler, exceptionHandler,  exchangePattern, isolationLevel, kafkaManualCommitFactory, batchWithIndividualHeaders, bufferMemorySize,    compressionCodec, connectionMaxIdleMs, deliveryTimeoutMs, enableIdempotence, headerSerializer, key, keySerializer,  lingerMs, maxBlockMs, maxInFlightRequest, maxRequestSize, metadataMaxAgeMs, metricReporters, metricsSampleWindowMs,     noOfMetricsSample, partitioner, partitionKey, producerBatchSize, queueBufferingMaxMessages, receiveBufferBytes,     reconnectBackoffMs, recordMetadata, requestRequiredAcks, requestTimeoutMs, retries, retryBackoffMs, sendBufferBytes,    valueSerializer, workerPool, workerPoolCoreSize, workerPoolMaxSize, lazyStartProducer, kafkaClientFactory,  synchronous, schemaRegistryURL, interceptorClasses, kerberosBeforeReloginMinTime, kerberosInitCmd,  kerberosPrincipalToLocalRules, kerberosRenewJitter, kerberosRenewWindowFactor, saslJaasConfig,  saslKerberosServiceName, saslMechanism, securityProtocol, sslCipherSuites, sslContextParameters,    sslEnabledProtocols, sslEndpointAlgorithm, sslKeymanagerAlgorithm, sslKeyPassword, sslKeystoreLocation,     sslKeystorePassword, sslKeystoreType, sslProtocol, sslProvider, sslTrustmanagerAlgorithm, sslTruststoreLocation,

sslTruststorePassword, sslTruststoreType;**

I have also tried the code but some classes are not found in camel 3.18.2.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaComponent;
import org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentConfiguration; // class not found
import org.apache.camel.spi.Registry;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

import java.util.Map;

public class CamelComponentProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.start();
        Registry registry = camelContext.getRegistry();
        KafkaComponent kafkaComponent = registry.lookupByNameAndType("kafka", KafkaComponent.class);
        ComponentConfiguration componentConfiguration = kafkaComponent.createComponentConfiguration(); // facing error this line
        Map<String, Object> parameters = componentConfiguration.getParameterValues();
        for (String parameterName : parameters.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(parameterName + " = " + parameters.get(parameterName));
        }
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the `RuntimeCamelCatalog` to get a JSON description of the component.

```java
RuntimeCamelCatalog catalog = context.getExtension(ExtendedCamelContext.class).getRuntimeCamelCatalog()
String componentJson = catalog.componentJSonSchema("kafka");
```

Then you can use your preferred JSON parser to inspect the `properties` & `componentProperties` fields.